# Can QuickBooks pass a URL to a Browser?

Tags: user-interface, customization, quickbooks

Is there a way to add a link or a button to the Quickbooks interface that will let me send a URL to a browser?

What I would like to do is query (somehow) the current screen for an invoice number (check number, PO Number, etc.) and pass a specially crafted URL with that number to the default browser which will call our document management system and displayt a document.

Other than the number embedded in the URL, I don't need to pass any other information.

I am not a programmer by any stretch, but I can entertain any ideas.

My other thought was to have an AutoIT script that will query quickbooks for the information and pass that along to the browser, but, I still have the problem of how to get that information from QuickBooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using a custom QuickBooks menu item, but it requires advanced QuickBooks SDK programming. The difficult part is placing the the menu item on the QuickBooks menu and receiving the context information that will allow you to identify the transaction or entity that is currently being viewed. Once you've done that, launching the browser is a minor concern.

You should be aware that there have been difficulties with the installation of custom QuickBooks menu items since the introduction of Vista. My suspicion is that the root cause is related to the changes that were made to the Windows registry in Vista. In any case, [programmers are still reporting problems](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=7&threadid=15709) with the latest version of QuickBooks and Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: Thanks,  this makes total sense and I probably missed in the SDK docs. Were mostly an XP shop here, so I will give it a try.